# Setting variables equal to 0 for multiple subroutines in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, variables, subroutine

I am trying to use a collection to set variables equal to 0 each time before they run through a sub. I have a bunch of metrics all as separate sub routines, and for each sub, I declare the variables as long and then set all of them equal to 0 and then have them pull from whatever data they need to. I'd like to be able to not have to set them equal to 0 every time, but rather set them equal at the beginning or something so it doesn't have to be put in in each subroutine, but I am unclear as to how to do that. I tried this code but I have no idea if it is even remotely right or where to put it:

```
Dim myVars As Collection
Set myVars = New Collection
Dim j As Variant
myVars.Add a
myVars.Add b
myVars.Add c
myVars.Add d
myVars.Add e


For j = 1 To myVars.Count
myVars(j) = 0
Next j
```

Comment: if they are global variables, you could create a new sub SetToZero() that you'd just run at the top of each of the other subs.

Comment: `j` is a loop counter, don't declare it as `variant`! Doing so introduces confusion when you look at your code later, as well as a slight performance penalty - each time you use `j`, VBA has to determine the _type_ of data contained in it. That's not a big deal for your loop of 5 items, but it will start to add up as your code base grows and you'll wonder why your code takes forever to run.

Comment: i get an object required error for j otherwise so how do I fix that

Answer (score 3):

If you declare your variables as numeric types (eg. `Long`,`Integer`,`Byte`,`Double`,`Single`) then they're *automatically* assigned a value of 0.

You'd be better off with strongly typed variables in any case, and it would avoid the need for using a collection or making the variables global in scope.

Comment: right but the actual physical value of 0 does not appear when I do that, it just leaves it blank

Comment: Declaring as a Variant won't do it, try: `Dim foo As Long : Debug.Assert foo = 0 : Debug.Print "Foo = " & foo`